# what is volume of produced gases in water electrolysis

Tags: water, electrolysis

I decided to try and determine the combined volume of O2 and H2 that could be produced through electrolysis of water. so i looked up a bunch of stats for the relevant chemicals;

|  | H | O | H2O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| g/mol | 1.00794 | 15.9994 | 18.01528 |
| g/L | 0.08988 | 1.429 | 997 |
| L/g | 11.12594571 | 0.699790063 | 0.001003009027 |

and then tried to do the math;

I imagined 1L of water being completely consumed with no other reactions and assumed that it would be a ratio of 2:1 H2 to O2 so i took the 997g/L of water and divided it into, 997*(2/3) and 997*(1/3) then I multiplied those numbers the L/g of H and O respectively, added them up and got 7627.60881 which deferentially seems wrong. I must have misunderstood or gone wrong somewhere because it expanding over 7000x in volume (at atmospheric pressure) seems ridiculous.

Comment: To nit pick (1) The density of water and gases of course depend on the particular temperature. (2) Given 3 significant figures for the density of water you have a ridiculous number of significant figures in the L/g row of the table.

Comment: thats because i calculated the L/g figures in excel (where i was doing the math) and it went a bit nuts with the significant figures

Comment: Excel doesn't know anything about significant figures. Significant figures are a crude way to do error propagation, but the method does keep you from inventing such wildly false precision. I remember my days as a teaching assistant. A student reported that a sample was 115% Fe. I asked *Doesn't that seem a bit strange?!?* The student replied - *But that is what the calculator said!!*

Comment: @MaxW I actually saw something like ‘90–105 %’ for the content of one element on the label of commercially purchased chemical, sooo …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not as far off as you think!

Here's the reaction:

$$\ce{H_2O(l)->H_2(g) + 1/2 O_2(g)}$$

It's often useful to first do a "back-of-the-envelope" calculation before proceeding with the formal calculation, since that helps give you a better intution for the problem and, in addition, gives you a rough ideal of what the answer should be (and thus serves as a check against egregious errors).  So:

As a rule of thumb, under typical lab conditions (room temp, 1 atm pressure), gases take up ~1000 x as much volume as liquids.  And since we're creating 1.5 molecules of gas for every molecule of liquid, our expected increase in volume is ~1500 x.

Now let's do the formal calculation to determine the actual increase:

Density liquid water = 1 g/mL => specific volume liquid water = 1 ml/g.

1 mole water = 18 g => volume of 1 mole of liquid water = 18 mL = 0.018 L.

Volume of 1 mole of gas at 1 atm, 23 C:

$$V = \frac{n R T}{p} = \frac{1 mole \circ  0.082 \frac{L atm}{mol K} \circ (23+273) K}{1 atm} = 24.3 L $$

Since 1 mole of liquid water decomposes in to 1.5 moles of gas:

Volume of 1.5 moles of gas at 1 atm, 23 C = 24.3 L x 1.5 = 36.5 L

Finally, the volume ratio is:

$$\frac{36.5 L}{0.018 L } = 2030 \simeq 2000$$

Thus complete electrolysis of liquid water at 1 atm and 23 C will increase its volume by 2000-fold.

Comment: Please correct the units "volume of 1 mole of liquid water = 18 mL = 0.018 mL."

Comment: @M.Farooq Thanks for catching the typo.